# How to run jenkins job via changes in specific git folder?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, multibranch-pipeline

I have one git repository where I have multiple folders, I want the Jenkins pipeline trigger when a specific folder gets changed.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure your Jenkinsfile to do that.

Take a look on Jenkins Built-in Conditions. You need "changeset" here.

e.g.

```
stages {
stage('yourStage') {
    when { changeset "FOLDERNAME/*"}
    steps {
     //.... what to do...
    }
}
```

}

[Jenkins Built In Conditions](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#built-in-conditions)